What am i missing in the xsl template for my navigation
I am trying to figure out the perfect xsl template for my html navigation.
Here is the html code


<ul class="menu-section">
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#">Accounts <i class="ion ion-ios-arrow-down"></i></a>
    <div class="menu-subs menu-column-1">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Login and Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Help and Question</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Privacy and Policy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Term of Cookies</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>



Here is my XSL Template:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="menu"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="menu">
        <ul id="wixmenu" class="menu-section">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="MENU/ITEM"/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ITEM">
        <li class="menu-item-has-children">
            <a href="{URL}#" target="{TARGET}">
                <xsl:value-of select="TITLE"/>
                <i class="ion"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="ICON"/>
            </a>
            <xsl:if test="ITEM">
                <div class="menu-subs menu-column-1">
                    <ul>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="ITEM"/>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </xsl:if>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

The result an getting is:


<ul class="menu-section">
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#">Accounts <i class="ion ion-ios-arrow-down"></i></a>
    <div class="menu-subs menu-column-1">
      <ul>
        <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">Login and Register</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">Help and Question</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">Privacy and Policy</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">Term of Cookies</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>



What i Want
I want the child elements [login and Register, Help and Question, Privacy and Policy and Terms of Cookies] Not to have the class "menu-item-has-children". I just want the xsl template to produce the original html code.

Your XSLT templates match elements that don't exist in your HTML input. There is no MENU, ITEM, TITLE, or ICON elements in the input.  I don't understand how you can be producing the output shown. Unless the first HTML snippet is the desired output? In that case, it would be helpful to also post a snippet of XML that is producing the current output.

Is that first code block the HTML output you want? At first I thought it was your input. You ought to always post your input as well.

Actually i am building an extension and to do that i will have to feed the extension with an xsl template so that the html version will be populated by the extension which will incude allowing the extension user to input their desired value for the navigation items. The first Html code is the output i wanted from xslt. we can ignor <xsl:value-of select="ICON"/>

Here's a version of your template in which the class attribute with value menu-item-has-children is added only the condition that the current ITEM element has ITEM children.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="menu"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="menu">
        <ul id="wixmenu" class="menu-section">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="MENU/ITEM"/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ITEM">
        <li>
            <xsl:if test="ITEM">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">menu-item-has-children</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <a href="{URL}#" target="{TARGET}">
                <xsl:value-of select="TITLE"/>
                <i class="ion"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="ICON"/>
            </a>
            <xsl:if test="ITEM">
                <div class="menu-subs menu-column-1">
                    <ul>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="ITEM"/>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </xsl:if>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

By the way, I wondered about your
<i class='ion'/><xsl:value-of select="ICON"/>

Did you maybe intend for the ICON element's text to be a child node of the i element?
<i class='icon'><xsl:value-of select="ICON"/></i>


Thank you very much your answer was very useful
